# no changes in bg color

Tags: theming

have inspected element for this [site](http://krom.club) and try as I might changing bg color in body for style.css makes no difference no matter how much caches are cleared.

I want to leave the tiled background and just change the inset white to another color. I didn't see background color in LAYOUT REGION sorry..this has been solved now.

Comment: it was just a css question not php or sql but i just should have studied the style sheet longer to find corresponding area.

Comment: both answers had no way of knowing which background I meant - my apologies for that.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the color is not showing is because you have this already:

```
body {
    background: url(images/body.png) fixed;
}
```

from `my_elegant.css`.

You have a background image already set. If you want to use a css color then you need to tweak the css for body to something like this:

```
body {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

or you can have an image background and a color at the same time:

```
body {
  background: #fff url(images/body.png) no-repeat center top;
}
```

If you are using `style.css` make sure that the file is properly added otherwise it could result to `404` and all the css in that file will not get applied. You can use `drupal_add_css()` api to add new css file or in the `.info` of your theme.

Comment: I want to leave the body.png and just change color of the white inset- how do I do that please?

Answer (score 1):

It's not Drupal issue, it's a CSS issue; looks like your site doesn't load style.css but it using my_elegant.css file"http://krom.club/sites/all/themes/my_elegant/my_elegant.css?nssjk2". Also you need to remove the background image and apply your desired background color

```
body {
background-image: none;
background-color: #FFF; /* yout color */
}
```

Comment: I don't mean the tiled background I mean the inset white I'm trying to change..